# Not able to access 3rd party in Nexus from Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed Nexus repository in my machine locally. I have uploaded certain artifacts to the 3rd party repo in Nexus. Im not able to access the uploaded jar from Maven. Im on a proxy so I have given the following settings in my settings.xml

```
 <proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>myproxy</host>
    <port>portno</port>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    </proxy>
    <servers>
    <server>
    <id>thirdparty</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <servers>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://central</url>
    <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
   <id>central</id>
   <url>http://central</url>
   <releases>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
   </profile>
   </profiles>
```

And in my pom.xml I have mentioned the following:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.custom</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>


   <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
   <id>thirdparty</id>
   <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
   </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
```

And, I get an error near the dependency tag as follows:
Missing artifact com.custom:test-impl:jar:1.1

I have uploaded the jar directly into the 3rd party as I dont have its POM.
Im using Eclipse. 
Can you please help me access this jar uploaded to 3rd party from Maven's POM.xml?

Comment: 1. Is your eclipse looking at the same maven that uses the settings.xml? 2. Are you able to see the jar if you search it in the Nexus UI?

Comment: According to your configuration, you are trying to access localhost via the proxy.

Comment: @ Eldad : Yes I have my eclipse referring to the same settings.xml and I am able to view the jar through the Nexus UI..@oberlies: I am trying to access the localhost to invoke the jar... Please help me resolve this issue. –